# Django - Python Markdown causes Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django

Everything is running all right when I do `./manage.py runserver`.

When I deploy the project to production server (Apache/mod_wsgi), there's an internal server error (see log below). If I remove the `load markup` line and the one markdown filter I used in one of my templates, everything's working again. I double checked I have markdown installed (otherwise it gives a different error).

Error Log: 
`[Sun Apr 13 15:50:39.642158 2014] [core:error] [pid 10823:tid 140116085417728] [client 98.253.57.200:35634] End of script output before headers: wsgi.py`

Since Django 1.6 doesn't support markdown out-of-the-box, I made a custom filter. Here's the templatetag file (`markup.py`):

```
from django import template
import markdown as mkdn

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def markdown(text, safe_mode=None):
    return mkdn.markdown(text, safe_mode='escape')
```

Here's the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% load markup %}


{% for post in posts %}
{% if post.published %}
<h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
{{ post.content | markdown }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

What gives?

---

**Update**: I've managed to pin down the problem to the `import markdown` line. Whenever that line is loaded, my server produces a 500 error. [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) seems like a good substitute, and it works. I still have no idea what the original problem was.